# Find the sum of all 3-digit natural numbers which contain at least one odd digit and at least one even digit.

Tags: combinatorics

Somebody please give me a hint. I want to work out the answer on my own.

Answer (score 3):

Find the sum of all three digit numbers.  Subtract the sum of all the numbers that have only odd digits and those that have only even digits.

Answer (score 0):

permutations and digit placement is key.

Comment: I understand that, but a little more of detail would definitely help.